# TypeError: elements.forEach is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, hashmap

I'm trying to iterate a map but the foreach returns error.

```
   this.mapObjeto.forEach((value, key) => {
           console.log(key + ' > ' + value);
       });
```

> ERROR TypeError: _this.mapObjeto.forEach is not a function

also the following codes doesn't work

```
   getKeys(map){
    return Array.from(map.keys());
}

getValues(map){
    return Array.from(map.values());
}
```

Comment: Can you show us `mapObjeto` itself?

Comment: any details on what are you trying to iterate over would be useful to all

Comment: Its something like this: 
name: "exampl1",
    addres: "exampl2",
    phone: "exampl13",
    number: "exampl1exampl1" ´

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access the keys of object and iterate over it. Object key will get the values from the Object. Here is the code snippet -

```
   Object.keys(this.mapObjeto).forEach(key=>{
      console.log("key ", key , " value : ", this.mapObjeto[key])
    })
```

Comment: @tcw9721 Please mark this as the correct answer if that's the case.